# Domain model validation in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, validation

What's the best way to validate an object when developing an iPhone app?

For instance, if an object has a number of properties each with their own rules - is there a standard library to implement? I'd prefer not to use some user-maintained library but rather some Apple-endorsed one.

Would it be best to write a helper method on the model and do the validation myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVC as a standard approach to performing validation (and to tying in with automatic validation provided by framework classes). Check the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html).